# Top Navigation disappears with the scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a navigation menu with the top bar that disappears with the scroll. 
An example is [this](http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/2.7.0/)

As you can see in this theme, the menu continues to be high but the upper div disappears.

How could I do? **Thanks** in advance to all

PS: I'm using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7AHb/3/). You can do something like this.

Key elements are:

```
// CSS
position:fixed;

// JS
$('body').scrollTop() > 0
```